# Are there alternatives to recline.js?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, visualization

I'm seeking a stand alone open source library that would allow a user to look at a data-set using multiple visualizations and options; chart views similar to those in popular frameworks such as Metabase and Apache Zeppelin.

An example API might be as follows:

```
var dataset = [
    {"year":"2017", "person":"Mike", "sales":50},
    {"year":"2016", "person": "Bob", "sales":40}
];

ChartEditor.at("#myDiv").initializeWith(dataset);
```

In the UI a user could switch between visualizations such as line graph, bar graph, pie chart, and even select multiple series.

Expecting to find a GUI editor based around popular libraries such as Google Charts, ChartJS, etc, it was surprising to end my search with Recline.js as the best option (only).

Do high quality and open source alternatives exist?

Comment: http://www.charted.co (MIT license) has limited functionality and is not designed for embeding in other applications

Comment: What's wrong with or missing in Recline.js?